# minuteInterval prop on react-native-modal-datetime-picker not working

Tags: react-native, datetimepicker

Expected behavior:
passing prop minuteInterval={15} should show time in 15 minutes interval.

Actual behavior:
1 minute interval

```
 <DateTimePicker
    minuteInterval={15}
    is24Hour={false}
 />
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation all the props provided by `react-native-datetimepicker` is being provided to this package. [Read here](https://github.com/mmazzarolo/react-native-modal-datetime-picker)

In the documentation, if you want to use minuteInterval, in iOS the display prop must be set to `spinner`. [Read here](https://github.com/react-native-datetimepicker/datetimepicker#minuteinterval-optional)
[image]

Comment: For Android and IOS I'm using the display as spinner. But I have no idea it's not working, Also I have tried passing value to minuteInterval as a state.